# Distributing 2R, 3G, 4B balls into 3 bags

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Randomly distributing 2 Red, 3 Green, 4 Blue balls into 3 bags with each bag containing exactly 3 balls. What is the probability

- exactly one bag contains all colors?
- exactly two bags contain all colors?
- no bag contains all colors?

For second part: $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4$ ways for bag 1, remaining $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$ for bag 2 and rest balls with $3!$ ways. Since any bag can have this combination we multiply by $3!$ and then divide everything by $9!$ to get the probability. Now for first part, I think we can use this same method but after giving balls to bag1 we can have rest balls with $6!$ ways. this will also include some cases from second part so we need to subtract them first using principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Is $3R$ typo in your title?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: @VIVID For second part: 2*3*4 ways for bag 1, remaining 1*2*3 for bag 2 and rest balls with 3! ways. since any bag can have this combination we multiply by 3! and then divide everything by 9! to get the probability.
now for first part i think we can use this same method but after giving balls to bag1 we can have rest balls with 6! ways. this will also include some cases from second part so we need to subtract them first using principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and try editing your post accordingly. Otherwise, you may not find others interested in answering your question, and it may get closed.